# Node.js Source Code Protection Like PHP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Is the node application protected in the sense that a client cannot view the source code as in the case of PHP. I am on track to building a website based on node.js but i don't want others looking at my server files, the client side javascript code is not a worry for me but  i want to keep the meaty server stuff under wraps.

Normally a person does not have access to the PHP source code of a website, is it the same case with Node.js ?

*forgive my lack of understanding, i recently started learning node so im not that savvy with it.

Comment: As far as I know 'node.js' is a Javascript framework that runs on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word: yes.

When using Node as a server, it'll work just like any other server.

Just don't leak error stacks to the enduser.

Comment: quick follow up, if i wanted to run a server from home just for my testing purposes one which i could access remotely, would i need to install nginx and then node or just node and run is as a server, thus keeping my code safe as it would be a server ?

Comment: Sorry, i can't answer that question. Maybe you should consider [asking it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?

Comment: Did you mean ask stackoverflow or rephrase it ? if so. You said if I use Node as a server. If for example I wanted to run a node server from home that I could access remotely. How would I go about setting up that server ? Would I need to install nginx along with node in order to get that server live ?

Comment: I have a test environment going, and i'm not using nginx with it. You might need to configure some way to access the server, such as giving it a domain, but i don't think nginx is required. I think it adds some optimizations and security though.

Comment: right thanks, i dont have a problem accessing it through an ip. Also if I make a test environment such as yours my code would be safe as the computer is serving as server ? just clarifying

Comment: Yep. Just make sure that you don't provide a way to access the files, or leak stack traces. (But for a test/dev environment, stack traces might actually be helpful.)

Comment: Thanks so much for everything